# javascript: Check multiple nested properties on a Json

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON that I want to check if has the following properties:

```
json.prop1.prop2.prop3
```

This method can check a property: `json.hasOwnProperty("prop1")`

Is there something that I can use to check all the prop1,prop2,prop3 at the same time?

Comment: json["prop1"]["prop2"]["prop3"] or used  json?.prop1?.prop2?.prop3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [Babel Optional Chaining](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining) plugin you can do this

```js
 json?.prop1?.prop2?.prop3
```

This is similar to

```js
 json && json.prop1 && json.prop1.props2 && json.prop1.props2.prop3
```

Example of using Optional Chaining

```js
const obj = {
  foo: {
    bar: {
      baz: 42,
    },
  },
};

const baz = obj?.foo?.bar?.baz; // 42

const safe = obj?.qux?.baz; // undefined

// Optional chaining and normal chaining can be intermixed
obj?.foo.bar?.baz; // Only access `foo` if `obj` exists, and `baz` if
                   // `bar` exists

// Example usage with bracket notation:
obj?.['foo']?.bar?.baz // 42
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use lodash get function to check nested object

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get

```js
const json = {
  prop1: {
    prop2: {
      prop3: "you are here"
    }
  }
}

console.log(_.get(json, "prop1.prop2.prop3"));
console.log(_.get(json, "prop1.prop3.prop3"));
console.log(_.get(json, "prop1.prop3.prop3", "Default value"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

json["prop1"]["prop2"]["prop3"] or used  json?.prop1?.prop2?.prop3

Comment: If you check prop3 this way, and prop2 does not exist, its going to end in a error.